# Freeze WPF UI - multi-threading in view model class

Tags: wpf, multithreading, caliburn.micro, freeze

Hi I use WPF with Caliburn Micro and in view model class I need test connection to SQL database.

Here is method which I use for testing connection.

```
    public bool CheckSqlServer(string sqlHost, int sqlPort)
    {
        try
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.Resolve(sqlHost);
            IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];

            var tcpCli = new TcpClient();
            tcpCli.Connect(ipAddr, sqlPort);
            tcpCli.Close();

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And I call this method in another thread

```
         //IP is worng
        if (Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(()=>CheckSqlServer("10.10.10.20",1521)).Result)
        {
            Insert();
        }
```

Problem is that UI of WPF still freeze I dont know why because I call this method in new thread not in UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

In your `if` you call Result straight away. That makes the calling thread wait on the task in a blocking way.

You should work e.g. with `ContinueWith` on the `Task`. That will be called once the execution of the first task finished. Careful with SynchronizationContext, though!

Also, you shouldn't call TaskFactory etc. in another thread. The whole point of Task is to abstract parallelism away from using the 'low-level' threads.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the proxy to null, so that the default auto-discovery will be disabled.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx